# getting top values from json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So I have currency for users in my python game stored in a JSON txt file. It looks something like this:

```
["user1", "300"]  
["user2", "500"]  
["user3", "45"]  
["user4", "250"]  
["user5", "750"]
```

Now here's what I want to do. I want to create a method which can return the top 3 richest users in the form of a list, that looks like this:

```
["user5 : 750", "user2 : 500", "user1 : 300"]
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: That file isn't valid JSON ...

Answer (score 0):

First things first -- That file isn't valid JSON.  However, the individual lines are.  If you really only care about the first 3 lines, this becomes pretty easy...

The steps are:

1. open the file
2. convert each line into a python list using using json
3. Take the n largest using `heapq.nlargest`
4. `join` the sublists using `': '` to get the formatting you wanted.

Code:

```
import heapq
import json
with open('your_file_name') as fin:
    pairs = (json.loads(line) for line in fin)
    largest_pairs = heapq.nlargest(3, pairs, key=lambda p: int(p[1]))
    print([': '.join(pair) for pair in largest_pairs])
```

Comment: this doesn't return the top 3 users with the highest values though.